# Hospital Stay: I cannot find a reason why my CalcTotalChargs is not being recognized

Tags: c#, linq, variables, calculator

This SHOULD work because, despite being declared as the last private double, the modularization of C# should allow the first CalcTotalChargs be recognized as well. This is preventing me from running the program successfully

**Here is the code I have so far:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;


namespace Adam_Zeidan_HW7CH6_6_Hospital_Stay
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void calculateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            *label6.Text = "You will be paying: " +         **CalcTotalChargs()**.ToString("c");*
        }

        private int CalcStayCharges()
        {
            return (350 * int.Parse(textBox1.Text));        // Calculating     the amount of days by $350
        }
        private double CalcMiscCharges()
        {
            return double.Parse(textBox2.Text) + double.Parse(textBox3.Text) +    
                double.Parse(textBox5.Text) + double.Parse(textBox5.Text);          // Adding together the other values entered within the textboxes to add to the eventual total charge
        }
        private double CalcTotalCharges()
        {
            return CalcMiscCharges() + CalcStayCharges();       // Adding     the number value of the sum of the previous calculation to the sum of the 350 *     Number of days staying
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a error? As it stands your code works fine for me and I cannot reproduce the issue (if there is one).

Comment: Sure thing! the error is in the line "label6.Text = "You will be paying: " +         CalcTotalChargs().ToString("c");" Visual Studio C# does not recognize CalcTotalChargs() and says that it does not exist within the current context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function spelt incorrectly, as such it couldn't complete.

`CalcTotalChargs().ToString("c")` should be `CalcTotalCharges().ToString("c")`

Use the code below and the issue should be resolved.

```
    private void calculateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label6.Text = "You will be paying: " +         CalcTotalCharges().ToString("c");
    }
```

Comment: How should it be spelled? I didn't think that would be the problem.

Comment: Trust me. You forgot the `e` in your method call and as such the method `CalcTotalChargs()` "_doesn't exist in the current context_". You cannot call a method that doesn't exist.

Comment: HAHA! I guess it's the simple things that get to me. I thought it was a technical issue. The code works fine now. I appreciate your help, Gabe!

Comment: No problem - Glad I helped